# Override the back button default activity stack action

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I would like to override the default behavior of the back button in my app so that it causes a particular activity (the activity loaded when the app is started) to be displayed rather than the previous activity on the stack. What are some good ways to do this?

Comment: Finish all activity when you make jump from one to another activity.
Do not finish FirstActivity.
You may only do this.

If you do this you need not to maintain any other onBackPressed() events etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finish()` all the intermediate *Acitivities*.

you can also use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
Intent mIntent= new Intent(mContext, mainFirst.class)
    startActivity(mIntent);
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

NextActivity is your main one

Answer (score 1):

When you are using intent to  go to next activity simply call finish() after that.
eg 
Activity -1,2,3.
Your flow is from 1->2->3

So when you call an intent from 2 to 3
just finish() activity 2 after that intent.
so you ll return to 1 when you back press.

Other option is to

```
@override onBackPressed
```

with intent to Activity 1.
but you ll have to make sure you have only 1 instance of 1
by using corresponding flag

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, FirstActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```